# Can you help to solve this triangle puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, triangle

Find the missing number (triangle)
[image]

Please write the logic also.

Comment: What is the source of this image?

Comment: it's taken from an exam.

Comment: "It's taken from an exam" is _not_ the sort of attribution we are looking for here. Also, PSE is not intended to be a resource to help you cheat in your exams.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Perhaps - when the OP took the exam, he tried and failed to solve this question, and now he's asking for help on PSE.

Comment: Perhaps! it's hard to tell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Result

> 52

Logic

> Add the numbers around the triangle. Invert the numbers from the result.

Examples :

> 5+4+12 = 21 -> 12

> 13+9+6=28 -> 82

> 17+3+5=25 -> 52

Comment: Please do not help people to cheat in their exams.